# how to perform dense matching between two arbitrary angle stereo pairs?

Tags: computer-vision, photogrammetry

I have stereo pairs from two orbits of a satellite. I am trying to generate dense match points between these pairs so that I can estimate 3D world coordinates using elements of Satellite-Earth Geometry.

*Question:* Which method/approach can be used for this arbitrary matching of the stereo pairs (which are not rectified so that x-only parallax is present)?

*So far:*
1) I am successful at using Hierarchical image matching based on normalized cross correlation which gives good results but takes a lot of time.

2) I have tried Semi Global Matching on images obtained after uncalibrated - rectification. But this method doesnot give good correspondence, though the disparity map generated is nice and smooth. Also, uncalibrated-rectification is very sensitive process.

Assume I do not have any camera parameters with me.

Edit:
1) The images are taken by pushbroom model with a line-sensor.
2) The images are neither georeferenced nor orthorectified, they are just radiometrically corrected.

Comment: You need to give a lot more details. Among them: are the images already orthorectified? Are the images captured with a line sensor (so the appropriate camera model is pushbroom)?

Comment: @Francecso C. I have added the information in the question itself now.